# x86 Segmented Memory

Tags: memory-management, cpu-architecture, x86-16, memory-segmentation

While reading *The Art of Assembly* the other day, I came to the section [here](http://cs.smith.edu/~thiebaut/ArtOfAssembly/CH04/CH04-1.html#HEADING1-64) on memory layout. It started discussing segmented memory, and I didn't think it made a lot of sense.

Splitting memory into segments makes perfect sense as a way for organization, but using the function `segment + offset`, what do you do when the function repeats its outputs? e.g. `1038 + 57`, `57 + 1038`, and `1095 + 0` all come out to the linear address 1095. Isn't that a bad thing? Wouldn't you accidentally address the same linear memory space when you didn't mean to?

Wikipedia says it can be used to an advantage, "for example when addressing multiple nested data structures," but how is this be used to address nested structures quicker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed an important part of the text how these address are calculated.

On the 8086, 8088, 80186, and 80188 (and other processors operating in real mode), the function that maps a segment to a physical address is very simple. **The CPU multiplies the segment value by sixteen (10h) and adds the offset portion.**

And dont forget that these addresses are always calculated in hexadecimal system.

Comment: But this still leaves this problem: `4 * 16 + 0 = 64`, `0 * 16 + 64 = 64`. Multiplying the segment by the radix doesn't eliminate the function producing the same output for different arguments.

Comment: Read the part of 4.4 Normalized Addresses on the 80x86, it covers you question ;) . As it states in one part, and as far as i remember from university year, they thought us like this: You have a memory of size N words, you can divide it in M segments each consisting of K words for ex. You would divide the address in its segment and offset part, but the offset would only progress from 0 to FFh which would avoid the issue when calculating the actual address...

Comment: Dont let those segments confuse you to much, contue reading on to see the parts on Code segment, Data segment and so on, it will clear things up. It's not a physical division of memory by any means rather an interpretation and representation used by the compiler and so on, you will see...

Comment: Ah, I think that section just clicked with me. I think I understand now. I'll make sure to give chapter 4 a little more time!

Comment: I very much doubt that the CPU uses any "hexadecimal system". it uses binary. hexadecimal is then a *representation* for *humans*.